How debug vue 3 app created by @vue/cli 5 while Debugger for Chrome is peprecated?
I juste want to create the basic vue3 current project with the current @vue/cli and debug it with vs code or chrome
vue create testApp
Vue CLI v5.0.8
? Please pick a preset: Default ([Vue 3] babel, eslint)

The page I found on the vue website seems out of dated https://vue3-fr.netlify.app/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html#prerequis , it asks to use vs code 's extension "Debugger for Chrome " which is peprecated https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
and the vue.config.js seems different
    const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})

Components in chrome dos not allow debuging

Do you know how to currently debug a vue3 app generated by @vue/cli 5 ?

adapt the vue.config.js allow to have more debugable Components on chrome. But it does not allow to debug with vs chrome
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  },
})


